# Запрет на скачивание видео, находящегося внутри тега video

Tags: html, видео, html5

Размещая своё видио у себя на сайте, помещая его в тегах `< video src="video/test.mp4" >< /video >`, при клике ПКМ выпадает меню, в котором оно доступно для скачки. Создавал .htaccess с запрещающими командами - толку оказалось ноль.

Подскажите, уважаемые знатоки, как запретить скачивать видео, которое находится внутри этого тега?

Comment: Зачем запрещать? Поставьте на видео свой водяной знак, и пусть качают, все что попало в СМИ и интернет становится достоянием общественности сразу же после публикации. Защитить свою интеллектуальную собственность можно только в момент (продажи/публикации), либо накладывая на свой контент определенные правила распостраняя его по определенной лицензии, при этом скажем при первом заходе на сайт вы должны явно пользователя предупредить, что он если хочет смотреть или качать, должен сначала согласится с правилами. А уж потом вы можете ему этот контент отдавать.

Comment: Это требует неоправданно больших усилий, но все равно не дает 100% гарантии, что видео не будет скачано. В любом случае видео будет отправляться клиенту, и тот сможет вытащить эти данные из браузера. Посмотрите, как работают YouTube.com и ivi.ru. Как бы они не старались, получить их видео не так уж и сложно.

Comment: со многих онлайн просмотров не скачаешь -- такая же идея

Comment: ну делайте видео потоковым, а не файлом и будет вам счастье. Хотя лично я не вижу проблемы в расспостранении контента и доказательствах его авторства.

Comment: как это сделать?

Comment: Не совсем понимаю вопрос в данной ситуации. 
Сделать это просто: установить и настроить сервер потокового видео (steaming video) сконвертировать файлы в формать скажем webm и показывать их именно через сервер видео скажем через vlc. Мне кажется в этой теме не получится вам все подробно рассказать, для этого у нас есть гугл.

Comment: мало того, что скорее всего оно вам не нужно, т.к. даже ютюб и подобные не могут свое видео от скачивания спрятать, если кому понадобится скачают, запишут вариантов много. Так вы еще потратите кучу рессурсов, денег и времени на бесполезное по сути занятие.

Comment: как-то делал проигрыватель, там находится слой поверх видео, правая кнопка не покажет его. но кто хочет, тот без проблем через консоль скачает его. 
http://codepen.io/NeedHate/pen/pjbrLW

Comment: Не помню как называется, но есть какой то сервис, который дает плеер, и он шифрует тем самым ссылку, и вы не можете ее скачать!

Answer (score 3):

Вот пример кода с запретом на скачивание видео.

```
<video width="512" height="380" controls controlsList="nodownload">
    <source data-src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 2):

Запретить скачку файла в данном случае невозможно.
Можно удалить прямую ссылку на файл, но ничего не выйдет.
Ибо для того, чтобы браузер его мог просмотреть, он должен его загрузить, а значит и пользователь может отловить то, что он загружает и сохранить себе файл отдельно.

Comment: плохо -- это значит что мою интелектуальную собственность могул скачать

Comment: Типа того.  
Иначе не было бы кучи законов, защищающих собственность, патентов всяких, лицензий и огромной кучи остальной дряни, которая мешает жить всем людям.  
Защищай лицензиями, патентуй, если это достойно него, нанимай адвокатов, чтобы стерегли твой контент...

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете отменить действие контекстного меню по ПКМ. Вы можете отменить просмотр исходного кода страницы по Ctrl+U. Но что толку? Те, кто в этом шарят, заберет то, что надо:
1. Видео - включить Camtasia studio или любую программу записи с экрана. Выставить таймер на время окончания видео. Запустить видео в полноэкранном режиме. Профит.
2. Нажать в браузере Настройки - Исходный код. Профит.
Не страдайте фигней.

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению, ссылка на codepen, которую привели в одном из комментариев к вопросу, уже не работает. Поэтому реализовал своё решение. Основная идея — заслонить проигрыватель нашим элементом и таким образом скрыть возможность несанкционированного сохранения видеофайла на устройстве. Однако из этого же вытекает и главный минус подхода, заключающийся в том, что элементы управления приходится реализовывать самостоятельно.

А для обхода такого препятствия достаточно открыть инспектор элементов из контекстного меню, щёлкнув по видео, и удалить узел `.video-curtain`.

```js
/* простенькая реализация управлением проигрывателем */
document.getElementById("trigger-b").onclick = function() {
    var p = document.getElementById("player-e");
    if (p.paused) p.play();
    else p.pause();
}
```

```css
.video-container > * {
    width: 640px;
    height: 360px;
}
.video-container {
    /* нужно для позиционирования потомка */
    position: relative;
}
.video-curtain {
    /* эти свойства перемещают блок поверх видео */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-container">
    <video id="player-e" poster="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj3wy.png"
        src="http://stack.astra.mymedia.su/enjoykin-druzhko.mp4"></video>
    <div class="video-curtain" id="trigger-b">
    </div>
</div>
```

<sup>В примере использована композиция «[Enjoykin — Лайки Крутятся (feat. Сергей Дружко)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y9MhHV0ndjA)».</sup>